# jQuery autoselect radiobox is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I cannot get my jquery code to auto select a radiobox. 
Here is my html:

```
<div class="formField rsform-block rsform-block-existingcustomer" style="margin-bottom: -22px;">

    <!--<input  name="form[existingCustomer]" type="radio" value="Yes" id="existingCustomer0"  /><label for="existingCustomer0">Yes</label><input checked="checked" name="form[existingCustomer]" type="radio" value="No" id="existingCustomer1"  /><label for="existingCustomer1">No</label><br/>
    <span id="component100" class="formNoError">Please tell us if you're an existing customer.</span>-->

    Are you an existing client?<br>
    <label for="existingCustomer0" class="radio"><span class="icon"></span><span class="icon-to-fade"></span>Yes
    <input name="form[existingCustomer]" type="radio" value="Yes" id="existingCustomer0" class="addRadio">
    </label>
    <label for="existingCustomer1" class="radio checked"><span class="icon"></span><span class="icon-to-fade"></span>No
    <input checked="checked" name="form[existingCustomer]" type="radio" value="No" id="existingCustomer1" class="addRadio" style="display:none;">
    </label>
</div>
```

and here is a snippet of the jQuery code that is supposed to do it:

```
if(aaid) {

var num_one = aaid;
jQuery('input[value="Yes"]').prop('checked', true);
```

Does anyone see the problem? I am trying to autoselect the "yes" checkbox, so that it will activate the next part which is create a dropdown menu.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: what do you mean by this auto select? i.e on page load this radio is checked. Or you just want to select it on click.

Comment: on page load it will be checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
   $(document).ready(function () {                  
     $('input:radio[name="form[existingCustomer]"][value="Yes"]').attr('checked',true);
     //OR
     $('input:radio[name="form[existingCustomer]"][value="Yes"]').prop('checked',true);
    });
```

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/qyYYE/)**

Comment: unfortunately that didnt work. I did however change your '$' to jQuery, but that should not matter. It also shows no error in the console log...strange.

Comment: yeh your example seems to work,...the only difference being you restructured the html. I have custom button classes for selecting. Ill try playing around.

Comment: yeh it works there, so weird how it doesnt work in real setting...ill try n work through it. i placed console log's, and they are all showing up...so its running the code, and finding no errors...its just not doing it.

Comment: Try using latest version of jQuery

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39455/discussion-between-bios-and-rhk-s8)

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple issues with your code here. 
1.  input hmtl does not have proper ending/end tag
2.  not sure why you wrap it around the label
3.  Be sure to put your jquery code in document ready so that it checks the radiobox when the page is loaded. 
4. in you html code, you are pre-setting the No radio to be checked. Is that on purpose? It looks like you set it to no and then using jquery to set it back to yes.

Anyway, try attr instead of prop. Something like this.

```
$('input:radio[value="Yes"]').attr('checked', true);
```